# Delphi OfficePartner Insert Section Break

Tags: delphi, ms-office

I'm working with Delphi's MS Office interop, OfficePartner, and I can't seem to find out how to insert a Continuous Section Break into my doc (this can be done in .Net via an `InsertBreak()` call). Actually, any break will do I can probably figure out this specific one if I get a nod in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean the TurboPower (now SourceForge, http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpofficepartner/) component set OfficePartner, correct? (Delphi doesn't have an MS Office interop set called OfficePartner - it has wrappers for the Office ActiveX controls instead.)

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why use the TurboPower components, instead of just using the COM (OLE Automation) interfaces for MS Office.

It's so easy to do OLE Automation COM interfaces (using Variants and not bothering about Type Library Imports or ActiveX controls).

Comment: I'm new to Delphi, so I don't know. I'll take your word for its easy of use and agree with you. Problem is I'm doing bug fixes to someone elses large and complicated application. So I still would like to know how to do it using OfficePartners ;-)